# What do you think is missing in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010

Even though SharePoint 2010 introduces so many great features, I am sure that at some point people will feel that things are missing, or aren't not working the way they hoped it would work - which in turn creates opportunities for 3rd party product developers to fill in the gaps.

What do you think is missing?

Comment: As there is no single correct answer that could be written for this, I've set it to community wiki. See more info about c-wiki here: http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/432/what-does-community-wiki-mean

Comment: There is a massive wish list in the comments of this blog post by Jeff Cate: http://sharepointsolutions.blogspot.com/2009/07/what-are-you-hoping-for-in-sharepoint.html It would be interesting to go through these and see how the pain points have been addressed!

Comment: 30 views - 0 answers. People must be very content with SharePoint 2010 :)

Comment: Still hoping to receive answers on this question at some point :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess I'll make the first answer ;)

Visual Studio is now a glorified XML Editor that makes solution deployment during testing easier. I was half-expecting List and Column creation to be done with a visual designer, generating relevant XMLs in the background. Seems the only visual provisioning tools we have are for Features and solution packages.

Answer (score 2):

Error messages and guidance to the user on how to fix problems, instead of Correlation Ids.

Answer (score 1):

Some things that have come up where I am working with this:

- Easier Search implementation (with either Search Server or FAST), crawls don't always seem to catch what they should and its not easy to determine where the issue is
- Better logging for errors, some things get lost between ULS and the Event Viewer, sometimes I have to look in multiple places
- Better SSL support with Claims, I don't even want to go into what we needed to do to get this work!
- Either put support in PowerShell or STSADM, seems that we need to use one item or the other to get configurations in place
- Some configuration settings can only be done ONCE when you set up sites

That should be a start...

Answer (score 0):

A *descent* documentation, that would make Reflector not a requirement anymore.

And self explanatory errors, instead of some obscure HRESULT (I guess it's a legacy of the first team services... but come on. We are 2013!)

Answer (score 0):

a tiny contribution: Cascading Dropdowns :)